# How to continue processing a block in Ruby after an exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to process some very large tab-separated files. The process is:

```
  begin
   Dir["#{@data_path}*.tsv"].each do |file|
       begin              
          CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t") do |row|

           # assign columns to model and save

           end
           @log.info("Loaded all files into MySQL database illu.datafeeds")
       rescue Exception => e
             @log.warn("Unable to process the data feed: #{file} because #{e.message}")
             next
       end
   end
```

However, when I execute this I get the following error:

```
Unable to process the file: /Users/XXXXX_2013-06-12.tsv because Illegal quoting in line 153.
```

The files are too big for me to go in and fix the error rows. I would like the process to continue the loop and process the file even if there are error rows.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just `... rescue nil` the row causing the error

you can even log it with logger

before the loop:

```
error_log ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/my.log")
```

inside the loop instead of just `rescue nil` use

```
rescue error_log.info(row.to_s)
```

in case you get the error before file begins to parse (before .foreach procedure) you can open it as raw file and read it as CSV later - inside the loop (like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671127/how-can-i-further-process-the-line-of-data-that-causes-the-ruby-fastercsv-librar))

..or just rescue full file parsing procedure

```
 CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t") do |row|
    ...
 end rescue error_log.info(row.to_s)
```

Comment: I'm not finding success with the method you suggested. If I change to rescue nil, the block still fails I just get no error message. If I use error_log.info(row.to_s) it fails because (row.to_s) does not exist outside the CSV.foreach.

Comment: I tried this.      
begin
  Dir["#{@data_path}*.tsv"].each do |file|
    begin              
      CSV.foreach(file, :col_sep => "\t") do |row|
        # do stuff
       end
      @log.info("Loaded all files")
      rescue 
        @log.info(row.to_s)
      end
    end
end

Comment: I actually got this to work by moving the row error capture to a begin rescue block inside the CSV.foreach loop. Thanks.