# Rescue CSV::MalformedCsvError: Illegal quoting in line n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, error-handling

Seems a common issue to have a buggy CSV file when attempting to parse to an array, AR model import, etc. I haven't found a working solution other than open in MS Excel and `save as` every day (not good enough!).

In a 60,000 row externally-provided, daily-updated csv file, there's an error: `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 95.` (as an example). I'm happy to skip/forget the malformed row (i.e. it has only 1/60000th importance).

First attempt is to use `CSV.foreach` or similar, and simply `begin` `rescue` `next` `end` to skip the error. No dice. I wish this SO accepted answer was a wee bit more verbose: [CSV.read Illegal quoting in line x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864064/csv-read-illegal-quoting-in-line-x?rq=1) (i.e. "just read the file yourself"--I think I tried that below).

And this SO Q&A ([How can I further process the line of data that causes the Ruby FasterCSV library to throw a MalformedCSVError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671127/how-can-i-further-process-the-line-of-data-that-causes-the-ruby-fastercsv-librar)) seems to have promise, but the accepted answer does not...quite...work in my seemingly similar case (modified for example clarity), executed via rake task:

```
file_path = "filename.csv"
my_array = []

File.open(file_path).each do |line| # `foreach` instead of `open..each` does the same
  begin     
    CSV.parse(line) do |row|
      my_array << row
    end
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => er
    puts er.message
    counter += 1
    next
  end
  counter += 1
  puts "#{counter} read success"
end
```

Output =>

```
1 read success
2 read success
...
94 read success
Illegal quoting in line 1 # strange that it says `line 1` vs `95`, which may be the crux of what I do not understand here (e.g. some kind of look ahead error)
96 read success
...
60000 read success 
  # I checked using `line.inspect`, and the 60000th row is indeed being read/inspected
rake aborted!

CSV:MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 95
```

Comment: sample lines ? would be great to have the 95th line and the surrounding ones.

Comment: i just ran your code and it ignores malformed rows and pushes everything else into my_array. Is that not what you want ?

Comment: shoot, @littlecegian, I thought because my terminal threw up errors, that the array did not accept the rows (I've never had error messages when rescue works properly)! I just ran `my_array.count`, and it had 59999 strings.

Comment: great! i'm just gonna put that as the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works. The expected result resides in the variable my_array.